# Changing content and URL in Postman requests

Tags: postman

I am using Postman to send requests to a web API. Of course the content of these are JSON. I would like to send these, but changing some part of the contents (for example here:

```
{
  "variable": 1,
   "variable2" : 3,
......(other stuff)
}
```

I would like variable to go: 1,2,3,4,5 or some other calculation (for example variable depending on variable2)

and also changing some part of the URL for example

```
http://someserverhere/v1/1
```

and the next time `v1/2` and `v1/3` etc.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think this question is not related to postman but to your web api.

Comment: @Shub  It is. I just found the answer here: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/intro_to_scripts  I just have to figure out some details on how to do this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, one question at a time, and you can ask here as many question you want!

> I would like variable to go: 1,2,3,4,5 or some other calculation (for
>   example variable depending on variable2)

That you can set it *Pre-request Script*. Find execution life cycle of Postman request as below:

[image] 
*Image from Postman Doc. find official script doc. [here](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/intro_to_scripts/)*

For example, I'd like to set `variable` value to 1 and `variable2` to 2.

Request Body:

```
{
  "variable": {{variable}},
   "variable2" : {{variable2}},
......(other stuff)
}
```

Things to notice:

- `{{variable}}` will use it as an Environment variable, and are suppose to be updated in  Pre-request Script.
- `{{variable2}}` is same as `variable`

Pre-request Script:

```
var variable = pm.environment.get("variable");
var variable2 = pm.environment.get("variable2");

if(variable !== null && variable2 !== null){

    //first time request
    pm.environment.set("variable", 1);
    pm.environment.set("variable2", 2);
}

//TODO: do other calculation
```

> and also changing some part of the URL for example
>   Change your URL and set variable from pre-request script

```
http://someserverhere/v1/{{someId}}
```

Pre-request Script

```
pm.environment.set("someId", 1); //generate dynamic number instead of 1
```